# UITableView Cell Data is Repeating When Paging - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I am using Objective C and Parse. I have a UITableView that displays photos from Parse. The first 10 cells load then you can tap load more for the next 10 cells and so on. My issue is in the same class that I am getting the photo, I also want to display the caption column. The first 10 cells show the caption correctly, it's when I page to the next 10 cells that the captions start repeating. The photos do not repeat so I'm not sure why the captions do. Below is my code that loads the UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

if (indexPath.section == self.objects.count) {
    // this behavior is normally handled by PFQueryTableViewController, but we are using sections for each object and we must handle this ourselves
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
else {
    ESPhotoCell *cell = (ESPhotoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ESPhotoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell.mediaItemButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnPhotoAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    cell.mediaItemButton.tag = indexPath.section;
    //The below line of code displays the black square where the photo would be.
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceholderPhoto"];

    if (object) {

        //The below line displays the users photo on the timeline.
        //The following 2 lines is what fills the display cell that shows the photo.
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        //The below line is what displays the image on the home timeline.
        cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:kESPhotoPictureKey];

        [cell.imageView loadInBackground];


        //Below is what I am trying to display the captions
        NSString *caption = [object objectForKey:@"caption"];

        if (caption != nil) {
            cell.captionText.text = [object objectForKey:@"caption"];
        }

    }

    return cell;
    }
}
```

Any help to this issue would be appreciated as I am fairly new to mobile development.

Comment: check for the right use of the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Comment: What is `object` in the code you posted? Where is the code that gets the data from your data source for the given `indexPath`? You need to update the cell's content every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called based on the data for the specific `indexPath`.

Comment: you might also want to check the cell's `prepareForReuse` method to make sure that the caption is being cleared when the cell is being reused.

Comment: Don't use `-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]`.  It's deprecated.